# iAd shows but doesn't react to taps

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I am developing a game with `SpriteKit` in Swift. I want to show the `iAd` on top on my game scene.

`iAd` shows, but when I tap it, it has no reaction. Nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
```

import SpriteKit
import iAd

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, BackToMenuDelegate {

```
var bannerView:ADBannerView =  ADBannerView()
var currentLevel:Int!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    let gameScene = GameScene(size:skView.bounds.size)
    gameScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    gameScene.currentLevel = currentLevel
    gameScene.gameViewController = self
    skView.presentScene(gameScene)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    bannerView.hidden = false
}
func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return willLeave
}
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    bannerView.hidden = true
}
func loadAds(){
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.hidden = true

    var adRect = CGRectZero
    let contentFrame = self.view.bounds
    adRect.size = bannerView.sizeThatFits(contentFrame.size)
    adRect.origin.y = 0
    bannerView.frame = adRect

    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
}
func backToMenu(){
    self.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    let skView = self.view as SKView
    skView.presentScene(nil)
}

func shareScore(score:Int){
    var objectsToShare = [AnyObject]()
    let textToShare = "I just got \(score) points in BlockCracker! Check out this App!"
    objectsToShare.append(textToShare)
    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=611627312&mt=8")
    {
        objectsToShare.append(myWebsite)
    }
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,UIActivityTypeMail,UIActivityTypeMessage]
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps it's because your banner view has zero frame: CGRect.zeroRect

Comment: I deleted the (frame: CGRect.zeroRect) but same result

Comment: You'd need to set a frame. See my answer.

Comment: Set a frame. And check if there is not another frame other the iAd frame.

Comment: @David I am new to iOS development  ,can you tell me the code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem. Just here in 
`func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return willLeave
}`
which `willLeave` default false! Just change to return true value.Now everything goes fine!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your banner view has zero frame (i.e. `CGRect.zeroRect`) and therefore no clickable area. You have to set an appropriate frame; and `sizeThatFits:` will help you get the banner frame sized appropriately for the current window. [(Code adapted to Swift from this Obj-C answer.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133198/2274694)

```
func loadAds(){
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.hidden = true

    var adRect = CGRectZero
    let contentFrame = self.view.bounds
    adRect.size = bannerView.sizeThatFits(contentFrame.size)
    // adRect.origin.y = CGRectGetHeight(contentFrame) - CGRectGetHeight(adRect) <--bottom of screen
    adRect.origin.y = 0 // <-- top of screen
    bannerView.frame = adRect

    view.addSubview(bannerView)
}
```

Comment: I copied your code to my app but it still has no reaction.Nothing changed.

Comment: @user1951072 OK, then something else is going on... Actually what happens when you put `loadAds()` in `viewDidAppear` instead? Any difference?

Comment: If I add `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`  It works fine but the ad is stays at bottom of the screen. I want to the ad display on the top of the screen. How can I do it?

Comment: without `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` nothing changed, the banner shows, but no reaction.

Comment: Once I add `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` ,whatever I set y position, the banner still on the bottom of the screen and clickable.Without `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`, shows on the top, but unclickabe.

Comment: Yes, with `adRect.origin.y = 0` still displays at the bottom

Comment: @user1951072 I've just looked into it and if you go with `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` instead of doing it manually, you'll have no control over the placement. There has to be some other reason that your banner isn't clickable. One sec...

Comment: Yes, it just let me mad

Comment: @user1951072 Just noticed something... `view.addSubview(bannerView)`. What's "view"? (It's not the same as self.view)

Comment: changed to `self.view.addSubview(bannerView)` same result

Comment: Just updated my whole GameViewController code . Please check it,hope you could help me

Comment: It`s 1:30 in tokyo, I must go yo sleep now. Thank you very much for your help! Good night! Hope I can find the answer tomorrow!

Comment: @user1951072 OK, since you added the subview to "view" I was hoping you'd had a container UIView named view within your interface to simplify matters... Because what's happening is in your viewDidLoad is that you're casting self.view as an SKView and then essentially using your self.view as an SKView to present `gameScene`.  So in presenting the scene the layout of the subviews might change perhaps...

Comment: @user1951072 You also don't have a call to loadAds() in your updated code

Comment: @user1951072 could you post an update underneath your original question containing your current code?

Comment: @user1951072 (I'm assuming it's not your current code since, as I said, loadAds() is never called.)

Comment: Thank you @Lyndsey Scott I found where is the problem is!